# Are all joins in JPQL equijoins?

Tags: join, jpql

I am referring to joins using the keywords [LEFT [OUTER] | INNER] JOIN only. Not to theta joins.
Since there is no ON keyword in JPQL, is it safe to assume that the equality comparison is always implied and used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JPQL joins are based on associations mapped with  @ManyToOne, @OneToMany,@OneToOne annotations.
When issuing a JPQL query the join is converted to the SQL ON keyword, for example:

JPQL

```
from Cat as cat
    inner join cat.owner as owner
    left outer join cat.kittens as kitten
```

is converted to

```
select c.* 
from Cat c
inner join Owner owner ON owner.id = cat.owner_id  
left outer join Cat kitten ON kitten.mother_id = c.id
```

So, yes, for JPQL joins it is safe to assume that the equality comparison is always implied.